# Delete div with image from server with data-id ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using wordpress. I want to make a script that will delete images from gallery. I have a script that deletes images when I click on button. Although it deletes them just from page, not server so if I save changes and reload page, images will not be deleted. I have a script that deletes all photos and this one should work likewise.

Script that removes all photos:

```
   'click .butterbean-remove-media' : 'removemedia'
                this.model.set( {
                    src   : media.filename,
                    value : media.id
                } );
        removemedia : function() {

            // Updates the model for the view.
            this.model.set( { src : '', value : '' } );
        }
```

I think that ajax script should look like this:

```
jQuery( function( $ ){
    $(document).on('click', '.image-remove-btn', function (e){
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'param1=2&param2=3',
            success: function( data ) {
                $(this).closest('.thumbs').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But I don't know what should be placed in `data`. I suppose that `data-id` that have every `img`.

Comment: Deleting them from the rendered HTML is not the same as deleting them from the server.
Do you want the script to delete all image files from the gallery or just selected ones?

Comment: @NikosGkogkopoulos only selected ones, I already have script that deletes all images

Comment: And to continue the case, do you select them from your admin panel or from the frontend? Please share some more information on the case

Comment: From admin panel. Admins can add, move and delete images from gallery. On frontend they are only displaying

Comment: then why do you need a script to do that? just mass select the images you want from the media tab and then press delete, there is no need for any script for that

Answer (score 0):

You must first get the special id of the image you want to delete (clicked).

To get this; The element of the clicked image must have a special id of the clicked image anywhere. Server with ajax by taking this ID of yours